# Tests fail in CTest but pass in QtCreator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to set up a simple Qt project with a unit test (written in `QTest`) using `CMake` in Windows.
I can compile the project without problem and execute the test **inside** Qt Creator.

The problem comes when I try to run the test using CTest (`ctest -C Release --output-on-failure --test-dir C:\SRC\MyTests\Test_SO\build`), as it ends in failure (exit code `0xc0000135`).

How can I make the tests to pass in CTest like they do in Qt Creator?
If possible, I'd like to avoid having to copy all DLLs needed to the executable folder.

## Test output

### Qt Creator

[image: test_success_qtcreator]

### CTest

```
Internal ctest changing into directory: C:/SRC/MyTests/Test_SO/build
Test project C:/SRC/MyTests/Test_SO/build
    Start 1: tst_MyTest
1/1 Test #1: tst_MyTest .......................Exit code 0xc0000135
***Exception:   0.02 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - tst_MyTest (Exit code 0xc0000135
)
```

## Things tried

1. Tell CTest to use Qt's installation dir as working directory: `--build-run-dir C:\Qt\5.12.10\msvc2017_64\bin`
2. Add Qt's installation directory to the Windows path in the main CMake file:

```
    set(CUSTOM_PATH "${CMAKE_BASE_DIR}/bin;$ENV{PATH}")
    cmake_path(CONVERT "${CUSTOM_PATH}" TO_NATIVE_PATH_LIST CUSTOM_PATH NORMALIZE)
    string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" CUSTOM_PATH "${CUSTOM_PATH}")
    set(ENV{PATH} "${CUSTOM_PATH}")
```

3. Set the `ENVIRONMENT` property directly at *test level*:

```
list(APPEND QT_DLL_PATH "${QT_BASE_DIR}/bin")
cmake_path(APPEND_STRING QT_DLL_PATH ";$ENV{PATH}")
cmake_path(CONVERT "${QT_DLL_PATH}" TO_NATIVE_PATH_LIST QT_DLL_PATH NORMALIZE)
string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" QT_DLL_PATH "${QT_DLL_PATH}")

add_test(NAME "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" COMMAND "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" WORKING_DIRECTORY "${QT_DLL_PATH}")
set_tests_properties("${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${QT_DLL_PATH}")
```

---

## Project structure

```
src/
|_ CMakeLists.txt
|_ HelloWorld/
|    |_CMakeLists.txt
|    |_HelloWorld.h
|    |_HelloWorld.cpp
|_Tests
     |_CMakeLists.txt
     |_MyTest/
           |_MyTest.cpp
```

### Source CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TestSO VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX DESCRIPTION "A test project with CMake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

# Initial guess for Qt's installation path.
cmake_path(SET QT_BASE_DIR NORMALIZE "C:/Qt/5.12.10/msvc2017_64")
cmake_path(SET QT_INSTALL_DIR NORMALIZE "${QT_BASE_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5")
set(Qt5_DIR "${QT_INSTALL_DIR}" CACHE PATH "Path to the Qt installation folder with the CMake configuration files." FORCE)

# TEST STILL FAILS #
# set(CUSTOM_PATH "${CMAKE_BASE_DIR}/bin;$ENV{PATH}")
# cmake_path(CONVERT "${CUSTOM_PATH}" TO_NATIVE_PATH_LIST CUSTOM_PATH NORMALIZE)
# string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" CUSTOM_PATH "${CUSTOM_PATH}")
# set(ENV{PATH} "${CUSTOM_PATH}")

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Widgets
    QuickWidgets
)
set(QT_DIR "${Qt5_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_subdirectory(HelloWorld)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(Tests)
```

### HelloWorld CMakeLists.txt

```
set(LIB_NAME HelloWorldLib)

add_library("${LIB_NAME}" STATIC
    HelloWorld.h
    HelloWorld.cpp
)

target_link_libraries("${LIB_NAME}" PUBLIC Qt5::Core)
target_include_directories("${LIB_NAME}" PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

### HelloWorld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H
#define HELLOWORLD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class HelloWorld final : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HelloWorld() = default;

    QString getMsg() const;

private slots:
    void myslot();
};

#endif // HELLOWORLD_H
```

### HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

#include <QDebug>

QString HelloWorld::getMsg() const
{
    return "HELLO WORLD";
}

void HelloWorld::myslot()
{
    qDebug() << "SLOT";
}
```

### Test CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Test)

# TEST STILL FAILS #
#list(APPEND QT_DLL_PATH "${QT_BASE_DIR}/bin")
#cmake_path(APPEND_STRING QT_DLL_PATH ";$ENV{PATH}")
#cmake_path(CONVERT "${QT_DLL_PATH}" TO_NATIVE_PATH_LIST QT_DLL_PATH NORMALIZE)
## this is the vital line, without it CMake set_tests_properties mangles the ENVIRONMENT
#string(REPLACE ";" "\\;" QT_DLL_PATH "${QT_DLL_PATH}")
#

set(TEST_NAME "MyTest")
set(TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME "tst_${TEST_NAME}")
add_executable("${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" "MyTest/${TEST_NAME}.cpp")
target_include_directories("${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" PRIVATE .)
target_link_libraries("${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" PRIVATE HelloWorldLib PRIVATE Qt5::Test )
add_test(NAME "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" COMMAND "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}")

# TEST STILL FAILS #
# add_test(NAME "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" COMMAND "${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" WORKING_DIRECTORY "${QT_DLL_PATH}")
#set_tests_properties("${TEST_EXECUTABLE_NAME}" PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${QT_DLL_PATH}")
#
```

### Test HelloWorld

```
#include <QtTest/QTest>

#include "HelloWorld.h"


class MyTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void init()
    {
        qDebug() << "INIT";
    }

    void test_MyTest()
    {
        QCOMPARE(true, true);
        HelloWorld h;
        QCOMPARE(h.getMsg(), "HELLO WORLD");
    }

};

QTEST_MAIN(MyTest);
#include "MyTest.moc"
```

Comment: `set(ENV{PATH} "${CUSTOM_PATH}")` sets the variable for the current process only. Set the variable for the shell you are running on with a shell's command.

Comment: So the reason of the failed tests is absence of directory with QT libraries in PATH variable, isn't it? This is actually easy to check: In the terminal where you run `ctest` firstly adjust PATH variable and then run ctest. If this variant fails, then the reason is *somewhere else*, so attempts to set PATH in the `CMakeLists.txt` script have a little sense. If setting PATH in command line helps, then try to set **exactly same list** of paths as `ENVIRONMENT` property of the test. And only if this attempt succeeds you could try to *programmatically* append QT path to PATH variable.

Comment: One typically gets error 0xc0000135 when a DLL cannot be found. Typically this can be solved via the PATH variable or by copying libraries to the application's folder (via, e.g. `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:>`)